# Matching strings with variations in spaces

Tags: ruby

I have a log file with a lot of arbitrary spaces:

```
Number of active files:    
       20

Missing files: 

      10
```

I am trying to determine if a certain string like this:

```
Expected_string = "Number of active files: 20"
```

is contained in the log file. Is there an easy way to compare the strings disregarding the variation in spaces?

I am using a method that looks like this:

```
def isStringInLog?(string)
  if open(@log_full_path).grep(/#{string}/).size > 0 
    return true
  end 
  return false 
end
```

However, this only works if the strings match exactly.

Comment: Could you format your `isStringInLog?` method please

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ruby's [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) method to turn all instances of one or more whitespace characters (including newlines) into a single space:

```
def string_in_log?(str)
  File.read(@log_full_path).gsub(/\s+/, " ").include?(str)
end
```

`gsub` uses the regular expression `/\s+/` to replace all groups of whitespace with one space.

Also, ruby variables (except Constants) and method names should begin with a lowercase letter and use [snake_case](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars), not camelCase.

Comment: This actually worked exactly like I was hoping it would. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe break and rejoin the log?

```
log = <<-EOF
Number of active files:    
       20

Missing files: 

      10
EOF

pattern = 'Number of active files: 20'

puts log.split.join(' ').include?(pattern) # true
```